Getting branches of a repository sorted by last commit date using Github REST or Graphql API
I want to get all of the commits across all of the branches of a github repository that happened on a certain date. I can easily get the commits of a branch on a date using the "since" and "until" arguments, but my problem is that I am working with a repo with almost 1000 branches, but less than 10% of them are active and it does not seem that the API lets you filter by active branches or last updated. I am only able to list every single branch in alphabetical order so currently I am forced to iterate through every single branch and check for commits on the certain date even though most of them are stale branches. If I could sort the branches by date updated, I would just get all of the recent ones until I reach one that has not been updated since before my start date. I am only able to list the branches of a repo in alphabetical order using the API and I cannot filter by any dates or anything so currently I am forced to iterate through every single branch and check for commits on the certain date even though most of them are stale branches.
On the Github website, you can easily go into a repo's branches and view them sorted by last commit date and you can also view only active branches, so I do not know why I am unable to do this with the API. I want to avoid doing any web scraping as I need the script to be reliable to be ran everyday.

This task is solved easier and faster with git itself:
git for-each-ref refs/heads/ \
    --sort=-committerdate \
    --format="%(refname:short) %(committerdate:relative)" \
    --count=100 | \
grep "days ago" | \
awk -v n=7 '$2 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 == n {print $1}'

This command lists 100 branches by the last commit date in descending order - latest branch commits first. The output is in the form:
branch1 xxx hours ago
branch2 yyy days ago

grep filters out lines when the branch is at least a day old.
awk is used to filter the lines when the last commit was 7 days ago.
More detail on awk command
-v n=7

Sets a variable n to the number of days we want to go back to the last commit.
$2

Refers to the second token in each line - number of days
$2 ~ /[0-9]+/ && $2 == n

A filter that selects lines where the value $2 is a number and where it is equal to the value of n.
For lines where this condition is met, the following statement is executed, where $1 is a reference to token 1 - branch name
{print $1}


But can you use git commands on a github repository? I do not want to make a local copy

Good point. You would have to clone. If you implement a GitHub workflow, it would be quite seamless. Checkout is very quick as it runs on GitHub servers and the git command is even faster.
